# Differentiate wrt Cholesky decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

I wish to find the most likely estimator of the precision matrix (inverse covariance matrix). One option is to maximise the following:
$$
f(\Theta) = \frac{N}{2}\log|\Theta|-\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i^T\Theta\mathbf{x}_i
$$
(assume that the mean is zero without loss of generality). $\mathbf{x}_i$'s are constant.

I know how to differentiate the above by exploiting the fact that $\mathbf{x}_i^T\Theta\mathbf{x}_i=Tr(\Theta\mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T)$. However, if I pose the question as instead to optimise the cholesky decomposition $L$ where $LL^T=\Theta$,
$$
f(L) = {N}\log|L|-\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i^TLL^T\mathbf{x}_i
$$
what is $\frac{\partial f(L)}{\partial L}$? It's really the second term that I am struggling with.

Answer (score 4):

To reduce clutter, define the symmetric matrix $$X = \sum_i x_i x_i^T$$
It is also handy to know that 
$$\eqalign{
  \log\det L &= {\rm tr}\log L \cr
}$$

Now use the Frobenius Inner (:) Product to write the function and its differential as 
$$\eqalign{
  f &= N\,{\rm tr}\log L - X:LL^T \cr\cr
 df &= NL^{-T}:dL - X:2\,{\rm sym}(dL\,L^T) \cr
    &= NL^{-T}:dL - 2\,{\rm sym}(X):dL\,L^T \cr
    &= (NL^{-T} - 2\,XL):dL \cr
}$$
Since $df = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}:dL),\,$ the gradient must be 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial L} &= NL^{-T} - 2\,XL \cr
}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial L_{jk}} (x^T L L^T x) = 2 x_j (L^T x)_k$

Comment: Since $L$ is a lower triangular matrix, the solution you gave doesn't look like it would give any zero elements. If I was taking a gradient descent approach wouldn't I end up with a matrix that isn't lower triangular anymore?

Comment: If $L_{ij}$ must be $0$, you don't take the derivative with respect to $L_{ij}$.  The gradient just involves the variables that are actually variable!